# how to scale (large) font-awesome icons from the react-icons package

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-bootstrap

I am using the marvelouse react-icons package (http://gorangajic.github.io/react-icons/fa.html), specifically the font awesome package.

If this was not react, then [I would just add an attribute to the  tag](http://fontawesome.io/examples/), such as:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
```

However, if I add the fa-5x to the FaFolderOpen tag, it does not do anything. As you can see, I am using react-bootstrap, and placing the icon a button (should it be a block)?

I have to believe this has been asked before, but I did not find it via search.

Here is what it looks like, and I want it larger:

[image]

```
const React = require('react')
import { Form, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Col, Button, Tooltip, OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap'
import FaFolderOpen from 'react-icons/lib/fa/folder-open'
import FaFileCodeO from 'react-icons/lib/fa/file-code-o'
import FaFolderOpen from 'react-icons/lib/fa/folder-open'
import FaFileCodeO from 'react-icons/lib/fa/file-code-o'

<Button type="button" bsStyle="success" block onClick={(e) => folderChooser(e)}>
     <FaFolderOpen />
</Button>
```

Comment: try this: `<i className="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>` it should work, because `class` is a reserved keyword so to apply `css class` we need to use `className`.

Comment: But the JSX object is contained in <FaFolderOpen /> What you are suggesting is good for non-react applications

Comment: are you trying to scale it larger or smaller?

Comment: I want it larger

Answer (score 129, accepted):

if you want a 5x icon size you need to pass it to the react class as `size`

```
// Font awesome pixel sizes relative to the multiplier. 
// 1x - 14px
// 2x - 28px
// 3x - 42px
// 4x - 56px
// 5x - 70px

<FaFolderOpen size={70} />
```

if you notice it jumps by 14 each time

[from the github readme](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons#configuration) it shows everything is overridden inline. its rendering a svg so you cant use `5x` you have to use a pixel size

#### Edit

Coming back to this a few years later, with newer versions of FontAwesome/ReactIcons the recommended way to handle different sizings is with their icon provider that utilizes the React Context API. This requires React v16.3+

```
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";

<IconContext.Provider value={{ className: "shared-class", size: 70 }}>
  <>
    <FaFolder />
    <FaBeer />
  </>
</IconContext.Provider>
```

Comment: ~Can you share the documentations where its recommended to use `IconContext` because I couldn't find any reference for it?~ nvm found it over here - https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#configuration for anyone else in the future looking for it.

Comment: @jarmos yes, the original link I provided from their readme is the one you just shared. Its been updated since the answer was originally written so i didnt feel it was necessary to add it a second time :) thanks for the clarification though for future passers by!

Answer (score 33):

In reactjs you can use `size = 'with your preferred size which be from sm to lg or 1x to 10x'`

this is example for font awesome 5 in react

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size = '10x'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to style several icons simultaneously, you can wrap them to IconContext.Provider.

```
<IconContext.Provider value={{color: 'navy', size: 42}}>
   <FaFacebook />
   <FaGithub />
   <FaLinkedin />
</IconContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 4):

An approach that is not very explicitly comes from [docs](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons) (close to **@Raimo Haikari**):

`App.jsx`

```
import {IconContext} from "react-icons";
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
import './App.css'

class App extends component {

return (
  <div>
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ className="myReact-icons"}}>
      <FaBeer />
    </IconContext.Provider>
  </div>);  
}
```

`App.css`

```
.myreact-icons {
  color: red;
  height: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default size is 1em. You can change it like this:

```js
import { FcSurvey } from 'react-icons/fc';
<FcSurvey size={'2em'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

React-Icons has a prop called size that can be used to set to any size you want.
after importing the react-icon from the react-icon library, you can easily do something like this.

```
<FaUsers size={'4rem'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement, because I was able to do it differently, you can also use the CSS property `font-size` or `fontSize` in JSON notation.

Using CSS in external file :

```css
/* style.css */
.bigIcon {
   font-size: 25px;
}
```

```js
// index.jsx
import { FiPackage } from 'react-icons/fi';
import './style.css';
(...)
<FiPackage className="bigIcon" />
```

or (JSON syntax)

```js
// index.jsx
import { FiPackage } from 'react-icons/fi';
(...)
<FiPackage style={{fontSize:'25px'}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a designer giving me pixel sizes that don't always correspond to one of FontAwesome's size options. So I'm setting the CSS height.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} style={{ height: "20px" }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this for increasing sizes of fontawesome icons in ReactJs

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faToggleOn} size='xl' />
```