# React-icons responsive size

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

How can I make react-icons icons size smaller for mobile? I understand pixel is not a good approach, but how should I do it?

```
import { FaSearch, FaFacebook, FaInstagram, FaUserCog, FaUserTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

    <FaSearch
        color="#023373"
        size="30px" />
```

Comment: Maybe scaling helps You: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768629/how-to-scale-large-font-awesome-icons-from-the-react-icons-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768629/how-to-scale-large-font-awesome-icons-from-the-react-icons-package)

Comment: I saw that, but I still can't understand how to make it responsive, is still a fixed size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@media` query in your case. Add a class to your icon component and write media query for mobile device width.

```
<FaSearch color="#023373" className="SearchIcon" />
```

In your CSS, do this

```
.SearchIcon{
  font-size: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .SearchIcon {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

I created a working example using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-icons-responsiveness?file=src/App.js)

Here's a list of all the `@media` queries for different device widths.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Comment: yes, i think is the only way. i really don't like media queries, I block their existence. but is always them. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to handle icon sizes on their wrappers. You can set the icon size to `auto` and change their parent size. You can do it on media queries or with any other method.

```js
<IconContext.Provider value={{ size: 'auto' }}>
  <App />
</IconContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in a tailwind solution, you can use tailwind's breakpoints in React Icon's context provider. See the example below.

Note that if you're also using Next 13+, `<IconContext.Provider />` can only be used in client components.

```js
<IconContext.Provider value={{ className: text-[1em] lg:text-[5em] }}>
  { children }
</IconContext.Provider>
```